# Maximum elasticsearch percolator query terms

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-percolate

Is there a maximum number of terms in an elasticsearch percolator query?

When trying to index a query that has over a 1000 terms, I am getting a StackoverflowError like this:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.apache.lucene.util.automaton.RegExp.next(RegExp.java:839)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.automaton.RegExp.parseCharExp(RegExp.java:985)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.automaton.RegExp.parseSimpleExp(RegExp.java:980)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.automaton.RegExp.parseCharClassExp(RegExp.java:912)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.automaton.RegExp.parseComplExp(RegExp.java:900)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.automaton.RegExp.parseRepeatExp(RegExp.java:870)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.automaton.RegExp.parseConcatExp(RegExp.java:863)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.automaton.RegExp.parseConcatExp(RegExp.java:864)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.automaton.RegExp.parseConcatExp(RegExp.java:864)
```

and that last line keeps repeating.

I have tried adding index.query.bool.max_clause_count with a high value (16384) to the elasticsearch.yml file, but that does not resolve the issue.

Is there a resolution or is it more appropriate to break down the query to many significantly smaller queries?

Comment: This setting does not affect the number of terms allowed.  It is the number of clauses allowed in a boolean query.

Comment: Your query is too long/complex for the parser to handle.  No setting will fix this.  Is there a reason you can't decompose this into a couple of queries?  A match on any would then be a match on your original.